# Acessing for loop varible in another python script

Tags: python, loops, module, scope, global

I have the file name as `file1.py` the code is following.
`

```
import os

global x
def a_function():
    while True:
        for x in range(12):

            cmd=f'rosbag record -O /home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/rosbag/{x}.bag /web_cam --duration 5 '
            os.system(cmd)
        
a_function()
```

`I want to acess x in another python script`file2.py` the code is following

```
from file1 import x
print(x)
```

but the problem is file1.py executed when i run file2.py. I want only x to be printed in file2.py

Can not acessing global variable in another python script.

Answer (score 0):

In order to correct this, add an if statement to check if the file1.py itself is being run. If it is, then `__name__` should equal `'__main__'`.

The code that you want to be read by `file2.py` should be outside the if statement and all code that you want to execute only if `file1.py` is run should be inside the if statement. For example:

```
import os

global x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def a_function():
        while True:
            for x in range(12):

                cmd=f'rosbag record -O /home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/rosbag/{x}.bag /web_cam --duration 5 '
                os.system(cmd)

    a_function()
```

Comment: I came across the following error.  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from file1 import x 
ImportError: cannot import name 'x' from 'file1' (/home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/src/file1.py)
`

Comment: The issue is because `x` is not defined in `file1.py`, which causes the import error.